# Java bean constructor with arguments and logic methods

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

I'm starting to learn about Server side development in Java and RESTful APIs and I don't want to use any framework for the persistence etc... except Jersey for the Endpoint of the RESTful API.

So I'll basically have 3 layers :

1. RESTful Endpoint
2. Java Beans (Pojo that implements Serializable)
3. Managers that instanciate the Beans and do operations on the database

My main issue is about the 2 last points.

I have read that beans only contain getters and setters and constructor, So I was thinking for a `Conversation class` use case, it could be implemented in 2 ways :

```
1. Operations and logic in the bean & access to the database on the managers
```

OR

```
2. Conversation Bean with only getters and setters & access to the database and logic and use of various beans objects on the managers
```

Which one is correct ?

At the time this is how my Conversation class Bean looks like :

```
public class Conversation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id;

    private String initiatorUserId;
    private String targettedUserId;

    private Date startTime;

    private Map<String, Set<Message>> assignedMessages;

    private Set<Message> initiatorUserMessages;
    private Set<Message> targettedUserMessages;


    public Conversation (String initiatorUserId, String targettedUserId, Message firstMessage, Date startTime) {

        this.initiatorUserId = initiatorUserId;
        this.targettedUserId = targettedUserId;
        this.startTime = startTime;

        initiatorUserMessages.add (firstMessage);

        assignedMessages.put (initiatorUserId, initiatorUserMessages);
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

What's the correct way to do it ? Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't sound right to have your database access logic in the bean.

Comment: I didn't meant to have database logic on the bean, only operations like : start a conversation, mark as closed, invite other people etc...

Comment: These are business logic that should not be written in the Java bean too. The primary reasons why Java bean is used are: 1. Provide a common convention how data is represented. 2. Encapsulate data. 3. Provide an immutability of data.

Comment: Thank you for the highlited points, I understand now.